# create dependent dropdown lists in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am new to Yii , and want to create dependent drop down lists, i m using cActive form ...
Am able to populate first drop down list but the second is not autopopulated

what im looking to do is when user selects a state in dropdownlist ist the 2nd dropdown list should get auto populated with the districts of that state only..

MT Tables

state_details

stateid
statename

state_district

id
stateid
statedistrict

view

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'stateDetails'); ?>
    <?php
        echo $form->dropDownList($model,'statename',CHtml::listData(StateDetails::model()->findAll(), 'stateid', 'statename'),
        array(
        'prompt'=>'Select State',
        'ajax' => array(
        'type'=>'POST', 
        'url'=>CController::createUrl('loadStateDistrict'), //or $this->createUrl('loadstatedistrict') if '$this' extends CController
        'update'=>'#statedistrict', //or 'success' => 'function(data){...handle the data in the way you want...}',
        'data'=>array('stateid'=>'js:this.value'),
        ))
    );
    ?>
</div>

    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'state_district'); ?>
    <?php
        echo CHtml::dropDownList('statedistrict','', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select District'));
    ?>  
</div>

controller
public function actionLoadStateDistrict()
{

   $data=state_district::model()->findAll('stateid=:stateid', 
   array(':stateid'=>(int) $_POST['stateid']));

   $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','statedistrict');

   foreach($data as $value=>$statedistrict)
   echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($statedistrict),true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `success` call updates the element `#statedistrict_stateid` but your dependent dropdown's id is `statedistrict` since you use `CHtml` directly. You can set the id explicitly using [`htmlOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#dropDownList-detail)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem still exists

Comment: What is the result of the call to your `actionLoadStateDistrict`? You can use Firebug or developer tools to check for any errors and what is returned.

Comment: Your post variable is `<ModelName>[statename]` not `stateid`

Comment: same undefined for statename

Comment: What is being sent to your controller? Use firebug/dev tools  or a dump of `$_POST` to check what is being posted.

Comment: What is being sent to your controller? Use firebug/dev tools  or a dump of `$_POST` to check what is being posted.

Comment: this may help you http://codingbin.com/dependent-drop-down-lists-in-yii/